# Issues in launching Android Application.

Tags: android, apk

Hi I face a problem in launching my android application.

```
Failed to install App.apk on device 'HT261W519228': Connection refused: connect
[2013-01-14 16:39:44 - App] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2013-01-14 16:39:44 - App] Launch canceled!
```

can anyone tell me reason of this and also possible solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is USB debugging/development enabled

Comment: Do you have the correct drivers installed if you're on windows?

Comment: Do you have a running proxy?

Comment: i work from morning it works fine but now i have a problem of this.

Comment: Try to kill the adb server: from command line enter `adb kill-server`

Comment: A firewall issue possibly. Believe it uses port 5554 to talk to the emulator, if you're using the emulator. If its a physical may still be a firewall but not sure if it uses the same port. I believe it does though

Comment: I solve problem by restarting my eclipse but I want to know about the actual reason of this problem. every time it happens i shut down my eclipse and restart it again.

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible that you are not connected to LAN or internet or any other network in that case Java will throw
"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" exception on client side.

Comment: @priya need clear explanation and your answer does not match the question